# How are transition functions of $TM $ defined when $ M$ is an oriented manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, orientation, tangent-bundle

This question was asked in my quiz of Differential geometry course and I am having a really hard time in this course.

Question: Let $M$ be an oriented manifold of dimension $n$ and let $π : TM \to M$ be it's tangent bundle.

(i) What are the transition functions of $TM?$

(ii)  What are the transition functions of the bundle $T^* M \otimes_M T^* M \to M?$

I have followed my lecture notes and I don't quite understand exactly how to define transition functions here?

I am also reading textbook of Frank Warner but I don't think he covers transition functions.

Can you please help me with answering this question?

Comment: did the lecture note mentioned the definition of transition functions? If not, you should ask the lecturer to clarify.

Comment: The definition is stated [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Tangent_bundle)

Comment: @ArcticChar I am aware of the definition you mentioned. It is covered in one of the lecture.

Comment: Then what exactly do you want to know for (i), besides the definition?

Comment: Do you mean the transition functions of $TM$ that preserve the orientation? If so, they are exactly the transition functions with positive Jacobian everywhere.

Comment: @TravisWillse but I am not exactly able to write formally, I am really confused with calculations in this course. Can you please help me how to write formally as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I'll address (i), which appears to ask which transition functions preserve an orientation.

Suppose we have two overlapping charts $(U, \phi)$, $(V, \psi)$ on $M$. Both $\phi(U), \psi(V)$ inherit from $\Bbb R^n$ the standard volume form $\operatorname{vol}$, which pull back to volume forms (hence determine orientations on $U, V$). The transition function $$\tau := \psi^{-1} \circ \phi$$ pulls back $\operatorname{vol}$ to
$$({\det T\tau}) \operatorname{vol},$$ where $T\tau$ is the tangent map of $\tau$. So $\tau$ preserves orientation---equivalently, $\phi$ and $\psi$ determine the same orientation on $U \cap V$---iff $\det T\tau > 0$.